# Text-only web browser that can log into google

Tags: internet, browser, google-accounts

I want to access my google account from a text-only web browser. I have tried several, but haven't got it to work. What is the problem? Is there a text-only web browser that can do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lynx works perfectly for me. I signed in at google.com

You'll just need to accept some cookies.

Comment: How do you configure it do to that?

Comment: There isn't a configuration per se, when you go to the site Lynx will prompt you to accept the cookies. You can then choose the "Always" option and it will always accept cookies from google.com

Comment: What he said! Yep it just gives the old Yes/No/Always/never choice.